# Access value from a Netsuite hash, Enumerator

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, netsuite, enumerator

Hi I am trying to extract a value from a Netsuite hash inside custom fields, and some others, which typically look like this - `

```
"custbody_delivery_ticket_number"=>
 {
 "script_id"=>"custbody_delivery_ticket_number", 
 "internal_id"=>"2701", 
 "type"=>"platformCore:DateCustomFieldRef", 
 "attributes"=> {
 "value"=>"123abc"
 }
```

}`  and want the value of it inside of attributes.

Have tried many different ways, but one in particular -

```
 delivery_ticket_number: "#{netsuite_sales_orders.custom_field_list.custom_fields.select['custbody_nef_meter_ticket_number']['attributes']['value']}",
```

throws error for class Enumerator, NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #Enumerator:0x00005589ec778730  which indicates may be getting close, but doing something wrong.

If anyone has any idea how to get values from these kind of hashes?

(Am told by the system admin that it is the correct custbody identifier)

Many Thanks

Comment: `select` is being used for filtering collections, not for accessing a deeply nested hash content. It expects a block and returns an enumerator if the former isn't provided. Take a look at [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-dig) istead.

Comment: Ok I tried  delivery_ticket_number: "#{netsuite_sales_orders.custom_field_list.custom_fields.dig(:custbody_nef_meter_ticket_number, :attributes, :value) || 'N/A'}",  and got error no implicit conversion of symbol in to integer

Comment: It is a  array nested inside a hash, and has got a name, like  delivery_ticket_number: "#{netsuite_sales_orders.dig(:custom_field_list, :custom_fields, 'custbody_nef_meter_ticket_number' , :value)}"  would be better if worked.

Comment: As with index its not guaranteed to be in same place, hence trying to get by name

Comment: Its got a script id also, so tried this          delivery_ticket_number: "#{netsuite_sales_orders.custom_field_list.custom_fields.dig{|x| x.script_id == 'custbody_nef_meter_ticket_number'}, :attributes, :value}",  but get error on first comma

Comment: Can you just post the output of `netsuite_sales_orders.custom_field_list.custom_fields` since the code works up to that point.

Comment: OK got the whole huge object, but a search for custbody_nef_meter_ticket_number was blank, it must not be there, might be in another list, am gonna look further and post back Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually fixed this, grabbing Netsuite custom fields with a select of script_id by name,and map as below:

delivery_date:netsuite_sales_order.custom_fields_list.custom_fields.select { |field| field.script_id == 'custbody_delivery_date' }.map { |field| field.value }.first

First selecting the script_id by unique name, then mapping to the value. Was able to get any custom field like this, preferable as they can move and might not have the same index if use an index to grab them, fetching an incorrect value. This way ensures getting the correct data even if the item is moved up or down in the custom fields list.

Thanks for everyones help!